# Weird js behaviour on custom drag and drop script

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, inline-styles

I'm trying to write a class for implementing visual drag and drop functionality in my webpage (yes I know there are some jquery plugins, I'm doing it for "fun").

All it has to do is to attach a mouse listener to a `div` element and move it when both `mousedown` and `mousemove` events are fired.

Everything seems to be fine, but when I drag the `div` more than one time, the script goes crazy.

This is the js I wrote:

```
var dnd;

function DragDrop (obj, horizontal, vertical) {
    dnd = this;
    this.obj = obj;
    this.horizontal = horizontal;
    this.vertical = vertical;
    obj.onmousedown = this.mouseDown;
    obj.onmouseup = this.mouseUp;
    obj.onmousemove = this.mouseMove;
}

DragDrop.prototype.mouseUp = function(e) {
    dnd.mousePressed = false;
};

DragDrop.prototype.mouseDown = function(e) {
    dnd.screenX = e.screenX;
    dnd.screenY = e.screenY;
    dnd.componentX = parseInt(dnd.obj.style.top);
    dnd.componentY = parseInt(dnd.obj.style.left);
    dnd.mousePressed = true;
};

DragDrop.prototype.mouseMove = function(e) {
    if(!dnd.mousePressed) return;

    if(dnd.horizontal) {
        var x = e.screenX;
        var deltaX = x - dnd.screenX;
        dnd.obj.style.left = dnd.componentX + deltaX + "px";
    }
    if(dnd.vertical) {
        var y = e.screenY;
        var deltaY = y - dnd.screenY;
        dnd.obj.style.top = dnd.componentY + deltaY + "px";
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="asd" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px; background-color:black; color:white; padding: 10px; width:100px; height: 100px">
    DRAG ME
</div>
```

I initialize the `DragDrop` class as:

```
window.onload = function() {
    new DragDrop(document.getElementById("asd"), false, true);
}
```

So it moves the component horizontally only.

As I said, if you try to drag the component two or more times, the `div` starts placing in random positions.

What am I missing?

There also is a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yUQTf/) if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it here - http://jsfiddle.net/yUQTf/1/

Problem :

```
DragDrop.prototype.mouseDown = function(e) {
    dnd.screenX = e.screenX;
    dnd.screenY = e.screenY;
    dnd.componentX = parseInt(dnd.obj.style.top); // This should be dnd.componentY
    dnd.componentY = parseInt(dnd.obj.style.left); // This should be dnd.componentX
    dnd.mousePressed = true;
};
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: Ok, my fault, thanks! I can't delete the question, so I'll accept your answer ASAP

Answer (score 1):

You're X & Y's are crossed:

```
dnd.componentX = parseInt(dnd.obj.style.left);
dnd.componentY = parseInt(dnd.obj.style.top);
```

Here's a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yUQTf/2/

Also, just some advice as I've implemented drag and drop many times, you might find it a little cleaner to attach your `mousemove` and `mouseup` on to window. This will allow you to move off of the div and still have it drag, as well as lifting the mouse anywhere on your page to stop the drag:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){ dnd.mouseUp(e); });
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ dnd.mouseMove(e); });
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really a stupid mistake. Thanks for the event listener advice, I didn't know about that!